# Matching datasets with on variables with inconsistent formats in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two datasets, one that lives within my agency and another that comes from an external source. Theoretically, all my agency's data should be matchable as a subset of the external data, but the problem is that there's no consistency in how PHN + street addresses are being recorded externally.

Our data = 100 West 10 Street
Their data = 100W 10th St / 100 W. 10 St. / 100west 10TH Street (you get the idea)

We have a lot of data, but they have even more, and both our data change on a daily basis, so it's infeasible to change formats one by one.

So I have two questions, coming from a SAS novice who's learned through work and lots of Googling, so please bear with me.

1 - Is there a way to do a quick non-perfect/fuzzy matching of the two datasets on addresses if they're not totally consistent in format? I understand that I'd have to go through the results, but I wanted a quick way to eliminate most of the non-matches immediately with minimal clean-up beforehand.

2 - If 1 isn't possible, what is the best approach to clean up the external data and to make the addresses more consistent? Should I keep the PHN + Street together, or keep them as separate variables? I started looking into prxchange and while it's definitely useful, it's not perfect. For example:

```
Address = left(prxchange('s / ST | ST. / STREET /', -1, cat(' ', address, ' ')));
```

Works great until it hits addresses at St Marks, for example, and converts the St to STREET.

The other problem is that I have to account for all the possible variations in spelling, abbreviations, periods, etc., which I'm doing now the old-fashioned way in Excel, but this leaves room for error.

Also, if some of the addresses have been compressed, such as 10west instead of 10 west, what is the best way to add a space or separate out entirely? Everything has been read in in the text format, and again there's no consistency in the number of characters to do a simple substring.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure this question is within the scope of SO, it's fairly broad. I would use a step approach, do direct matches first and then look for fuzzy matches, using SOUNDEX, SOUNDS LIKE and COMPGED functions. Keep PHN and street separate, it's likely if PHN match its the same person, even if the address is different.  If you have access to SAS data flux I believe it helps to standardize addresses. If you also search on Lexjansen.com there are several papers written on this topic with several macros available. Don't reinvent the wheel or start from scratch!

Comment: Never tried it, but might be worth a shot: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Standardizing_Addresses_in_SAS_for_Geocoding